# Comparing date with the Result Set in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Below is my query which is going to Generate two rows for me after execution of the query.

```
SELECT *FROM ELP_COUNTRY,ELP_COUNTRY_Tax where 
 ELP_COUNTRY.COUNTRY_ID=Elp_Country_Tax.Country_Id  
 and ELP_COUNTRY.DESCRIPTION='Brasil' and GETENGLISHDESCFROMLISTITEM(ELP_COUNTRY_TAX.TAX_TYPE_ID)='Premiums'
 and ELP_COUNTRY_TAX.DEALER_ID is  null
```

This query is returning two rows and again from that rows there is a date named effective date. so again from those rows I want to get the Highest date.

Can anyone help me on this. I am new to Oracle

Comment: Which fields do you actually want to return?  You can do a MAX(effdt) or just an order by effdt DESC with what you're looking to return.

Comment: I want to return only some fields not all

Comment: see @Liss my query will return two rows again from that two rows I want to get the maximum date

Comment: You're doing a select *, so you haven't told us what fields you're trying to pull as we cannot see the table or output....

Answer (score 0):

You could self-join the table with the effective date and evaluate against that by adding something like this: (note the joins may not be correct since I'm just guessing what table the effective date is in and how the tables are related)

```
and elp_country.effective_date = (select max(e2.effective_date) from elp_country e2 where e2.country_id = elp_country.country_id and elp_country.description = 'Brasil')
```

Or if it's just a grouping thing you're trying to do then your select would be something like this:

```
SELECT max(effective_date), column2, column3
FROM ELP_COUNTRY,
ELP_COUNTRY_Tax 
where ELP_COUNTRY.COUNTRY_ID=Elp_Country_Tax.Country_Id  
and ELP_COUNTRY.DESCRIPTION='Brasil' and 
GETENGLISHDESCFROMLISTITEM(ELP_COUNTRY_TAX.TAX_TYPE_ID)='Premiums'
 and ELP_COUNTRY_TAX.DEALER_ID is  null 
group by column2, column3;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the rank function, and wrap that with a "select *" and a where clause predicate filtering the rank of 1, like so:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT 
    c.*, 
    ct.*,
    rank() over (order by ct.effective_date) as eff_date_rnk
  FROM 
    ELP_COUNTRY c,
    ELP_COUNTRY_Tax ct
  WHERE 
    ELP_COUNTRY.COUNTRY_ID = Elp_Country_Tax.Country_Id  
    and ELP_COUNTRY.DESCRIPTION='Brasil' 
    and GETENGLISHDESCFROMLISTITEM(ELP_COUNTRY_TAX.TAX_TYPE_ID)='Premiums'
    and ELP_COUNTRY_TAX.DEALER_ID is  null
) t
WHERE t.eff_date_rnk = 1;
```